# how to find minor and major dimension after compression on ANSYS

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, ansys

at the begining,in this models inner diameter 2in,outer diameter 4 inc.I want to find out changes of the shape after compression as inc.

[image]R9.jpg